# Comunicação entre micro serviços

Tags: c#, microsserviços, dotnet-cli

Olá

Estou a desenvolver uma arquitectura em micro serviços em dotnet de um software na área do retalho (varejo, para quem é pt-br). Tenho três micro serviços: Cliente, Catálogo e Comando.

1. Cliente: todos os dados relativos aos clientes.
2. Catálogo: todos os dados dos produtos, incluindo o preço.
3. Order: representa uma compra.

Tem os seguintes endpoints e respostas esperadas:

**Order**

```
{ 
  "idOrder" : number,
  [ 
    { "idArticle" : number,
      "quantity" : number 
    } 
  ],
  "idCustomer" : number,
  "total" : number
}
```

**OrderDetails**:

```
{ 
  "idOrder" : number,
  [ 
    { "article" : { 
        "idArticle" : number,
        "name" : string,
        "price" : number,
        "stock" : number,
        "description" : string
      },
      "quantity" : number 
    } 
  ],
  "customer" : {
    "idCustomer" : number,
    "lastname" : string,
    "firstname" : string,
    "gender" : string,
    "address" string,
    "mail": string,
    "phone": string
  },
  "total" : number

}
```

**Customer**:

```
{
  "idCustomer" : number,
  "lastname" : string,
  "firstname" : string,
  "gender" : string,
  "address" string,
  "mail": string,
  "phone": string
}
```

**Article**:

```
{ 
  "idArticle" : number,
  "name" : string,
  "price" : number,
  "stock" : number,
  "description" : string
}
```

Para dar resposta ao endpoint do OrderDetails preciso de fazer comunicação entre os micro serviços Order -> client e Order -> Article. Sabem a melhor a forma de fazer comunicação entre microserviços com base em eventos? Preciso verificar se o artigo existe e se tem stock, parece-me que tem que ser um evento sincrono.

Obrigado.

Comment: dê uma olhada em serviços de mensageria, como por exemplo rabbitmq

Comment: @LucasMiranda Obrigado pela resposta. Mas com serviços de mensageira consigo fazer mensagens síncronas? Isto é o micro serviço Order consegue esperar por uma mensagem? Pensava que era só para mensagens assíncronas.

Comment: dá pra fazer, mas isso já me faria repensar a estrutura dos seus microserviços, já que se você precisasse escalonar, ia precisar subir os 3, ao meu ver se existe essa forte dependência, o ideal é que eles fiquem juntos, tem que ter muito cuidado pra não acabar fazendo um monolito disfarçado de microserviço

Comment: @LucasMiranda Percebo o que dizes mas a verdade é que a granularidade dos micro serviços também é importante. Se não for muito fina tmb começamos a ter um monolitico disfarçado.